# Getting option name php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am new to PHP so bear with me. I have some code like this -

```
echo ('<select name="fullname">');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($dorequest)) {
  echo ('<option name="' . $row['ID'] . '">' . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] .  '</option>'); 
}
echo('</select>');
```

Which works fine. When I submit the form I want to get the ID of the selected option ( $row['ID'] ). I can only get the content of the select box. Any ideas how I might do this?

Comment: Your output is not escaped. Carefully check whether htmlspecialchars() is needed - which is the case whenever you want to write plain text that does not contain any HTML into HTML. You hopefully also escaped the SQL query data...

Comment: @Sven I'm not sure what you mean. Do you have a link to a good tutorial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `value` attribute instead of `name`:

```
echo ('<option name="' . $row['ID'] . '">' . $row['firstname'] ...
                ^-------HERE, use "value" instead of "name"
```

As the name for the sending variable is already set in your select `<select name="fullname">` what you need to specify in the `<option>` is the `value` you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

You should being using:

```
echo ('<option value="' . $row['ID'] . '">' . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] .  '</option>');
```

Note I changed `name` to `value`.  Options have values, not names.  The input name is determined by the property in the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

If your using post for your select form, then during the while loop you could add

`$ShowID = $rows['ID'];`

Then on your query during the post function you could use the `$ShowID` on your query or echo it out using `echo $ShowID;`